# How to use timezones with php dates?

Tags: php, mysql, timezone, utc

I have a `PHP` page that is pulling in a date string.

```
eg. 2012-11-10 11:37:06
```

I know that this time is in a specific timezone.

I want to store this date in `UTC` time in a `MySQL` date field so that it can later be converted to a client's local time.

How can I do this in `PHP`?

Answer (score 3):

To convert timezones, use the DateTime class http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

```
// Create a DateTime object with your local time and local timezone.
$d = new DateTime('2012-11-10 11:37:06', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Auckland'));

// Convert to UTC
$d->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

// outputs 2012-11-09 22:37:06
echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Will the `$d` on its own be suitable for insertion into a `MySQL` date field? eg. `"UPDATE Table1 SET Date1 = $d"`

Comment: This is correct, but you also need to make sure your MySQL connection timezone setting is UTC, by issuing this command: `SET time_zone = '+0:00';` before you do your `UPDATE` command.  If you know, for sure, that your MySQL machine's default time zone setting is UTC you can skip this step.